# How to append multiple Paths to PYTHONPATH programmatically

Tags: python, path, pythonpath

I have 4 directories:

```
/home/user/test1
/home/user/test2
/home/user/test3
/home/user/test4
```

I have another directory with tests

```
/home/user/testing
```

having the file testall.py

ow, how can I append PATHS, for test1 thru test4 to PYTHONPATH so that I can access the files under test1 thru 4.

btw, test1 thru 4 have multiple directories under them where the python files are located.

I tried:

```
import sys
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"test1"))
sys.path.insert(1,os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"test2"))
sys.path.insert(2,os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"test3"))
sys.path.insert(3,os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,"test4"))
```

did not seem to work

also:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/test1','/home/user/test2','/home/user/test3','/home/kahmed/test4')
from test1.common.api import GenericAPI
```

did not work.

basically:
from test1.common.api import GenericAPI
should work

Comment: Do you want to do this in a python script? (`sys.path.append(path)`), from you bash shell? `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:path1:path2:path3:path4`, from csh like shells? `setenv PYTHONPATH ${PYTHONPATH}:path1:path2:path3:path4`

Comment: i alos tried using bash and appending this line in /etc/profile
export PATHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/user/test1:/home/user/test2:/home/user/test3:/home/user/test4
but when i do echo $PYTHONPATH, i get nothing

Comment: Why -2, even though i tried many solution ?

Comment: do the directories have an `__init__.py` file in them (this makes a directory a module)?  If not, put one in and then try `sys.path.append('/home/user'); from test1.common.api import ...`.

Comment: After changing your /etc/profile **did you log out and log in again**? The system profile file is only re-read upon login. Alternatively, just execute that command directly in your current shell...

Comment: Please **detail your question** by adding the **exact** location of your `GenericAPI` class (the correct path name it should be loaded from!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/')
from test1.common.api import GenericAPI
```

It is not recommended, but will maybe do what you meant to do? Because I guess your files are *not* in the folder `/home/user/test1/test1/common/api/` ...

Given a python path of `["a", "b", "c"]`, trying to `import a.b.c` will look in `a/a/b/c`, then `b/a/b/c` and `c/a/b/c`. However, *NOT* in `a/b/c`. There is no matching of the module name *starting* with `a` and the python path *ending* with `a` and then leaving out one of the `a`s. It strictly is path + module, not part-of-path + part-of-module.

Since your question is about "multiple paths", does a *single* path work for you yet? Doesn't seem so...

Comment: this works, but i will still search for a universal solution, where the directories dont have to be hardcoded, and use relative paths. No it did not work for a single path.

Answer (score 12):

`sys.path.append('/home/user/test1','/home/user/test2', ...)` does not work because `append()` function can take only 1 argument.

What you could use instead is:

```
import sys
sys.path += ['/home/user/test1','/home/user/test2','/home/user/test3','/home/kahmed/test4']
```

Comment: doesn't work on python3.7.4. I still have to do `sys.path.append()` on individual item to make python recognize those paths.

Comment: @user3342981 Just tested on 3.7.5 and it works. Check last elements of sys.path list, added path's will be there. `+=` operator is an equivalent to `.extend()`, which works exactly like `.append()` but accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: Solution works for multiple paths only. For single path, it weirdly adds every character to path. Try `sys.path += ('/home/user/test1'); print(sys.path)`. P.S. I know question is about multiple paths.

Comment: @user3342981 do `sys.path += ['/home/user/test1']` for single path.

Answer (score 0):

More like this:

```
sys.path.append \
("C:\\Program Files\\DIgSILENT\\...");("C:\\Programs\\eclipse...")
```